# useState setter functions not updating state when using spread operator and multiple if statements?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

Sorry for the confusing title. Here is my code:

```
if (user.name === '') {
  console.log('name empty')
  setErrors({ ...errors, name: 'You must enter your name.' })
} else {
  console.log('name not empty')
  setErrors({ ...errors, name: '' })
}

if (user.email === '') {
  setErrors({ ...errors, email: 'You must enter a valid email.' })
} else {
  setErrors({ ...errors, email: '' })
}

if (user.password === '') {
  setErrors({ ...errors, password: 'You must enter a password.' })
} else {
  setErrors({ ...errors, password: '' })
}
```

So basically, the only if statement that works here is for the password field. If i comment that out, only the email field would work. It seems that only the last setter function works, I feel like it might have something to do with the spread operator saving the old state before it can be updated.

Answer (score 2):

While you could use callbacks instead, eg

```
setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, // ...
```

it looks like it would be a lot easier to call `setErrors` only once:

```
setErrors({
  // if these are the only properties,
  // no need for `...errors`
  name: user.name === '' ? 'You must enter your name.' : '',
  email: user.email === '' ? 'You must enter a valid email.' : '',
  password: user.password === '' ? 'You must enter a password.' : '',
});
```

If this is in a `<form>`, you could also consider adding a `required` attribute instead of checking all these manually.

Answer (score 0):

your code actually updates state 3 times. It's not the spread operator guilt, but the fact you are passing the same `error` object state to each state update, and that `error` has no errors.

This way, each subsequent state update overwrites the previous one with the outdated state `error`, where it doesn't have any errors.

In these situations to reach the desired outcome you must pass a callback function to `setErrors`. That callback will receive as argument the current state.

if you change each `setErrors`:

```
setErrors({ ...errors, name: 'You must enter your name.' })
```

to receive a callback:

```
setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, name: 'You must enter your name.' }))
```

You will see that your `errors` state will update correctly, since the callback function receives the current state object.

Note: Obviously @CertainPerformance is a much cleaner code.